# Preventing a Pyramid of Doom using rxjs .subscribe with Angular - flattening the number of .subscribes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm currently looking into [RxJS's .merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) however I'll also ask the question here as I find explanations here at times to be brilliant.

Okay, I have a form that depending on user input opens a modal window, I subscribe to the modal close event and pass back some data that I will use after I call / subscribe to a service method to retrieve some data, then when this has happened I do the same again and call / subscribe another service method to update some date then when this has finished I run a local method. So what I have here is 3 nested `.subscribe`s

```
const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(ModalWindowComponent, {});
let userId = 4; // this is the real world is selected by the user
let userData = {}; // this is actually form data created by the user

// dialog is closed
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
  if (typeof result === 'string') {
     // subscribe to a service to get some data
     this.userService.getUser(userId).subscribe((user: any) => {
        // do something with the data
        let mergedObj = Object.assign({}, user, {newProperty: result});
          // subscribe to another service to update the data
          this.scbasService.updateUser(userId, mergedObj).subscribe(() => {
             this.doSomethingElse(userData); 
      });
    });
  }
});
```

What I have here is a "pyramid of doom". I remember when working with AngularJS and working with promises I could return the next service and have chained `.then()`s. I really want to flatten my code, any ideas?

How could I do the same here so my code doesn't indent constantly?

If I haven't asked or explained myself so well please say so and I will rephrase my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
dialogRef
  .afterClosed()
  .filter(result => typeof result === 'string')
  .mergeMap(result => this.userService
    .getUser(userId)
    .mergeMap(user => {
      let mergedObj = Object.assign({}, user, { newProperty: result });
      return this.scbasService.updateUser(userId, mergedObj);
    })
  )
  .do(() => this.doSomethingElse(userData))
  .subscribe();
```

- Use `filter` so that only `string` results are processed.
- Use `mergeMap` to compose an inner observable for the `getUser` and `updateUser` calls.
- Use `mergeMap` again to merge the inner observable into the outer observable.
- Use `do` to do something after the user is updated.
- And call `subscribe`. Otherwise, nothing will happen.

Something to keep in mind is that nesting `subscribe` calls within `subscribe` calls is an antipattern.

If you want, you could flatten it further, using the result selector in the first `mergeMap` to add the property:

```
dialogRef
  .afterClosed()
  .filter(result => typeof result === 'string')
  .mergeMap(
    result => this.userService.getUser(userId),
    (result, user) => Object.assign({}, user, { newProperty: result })
  )
  .mergeMap(
    userWithNewProperty => this.scbasService.updateUser(userId, userWithNewProperty)
  )
  .do(() => this.doSomethingElse(userData))
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: That is fantastic -  a great answer, well explained however what if I want to perform an action with results that aren't strings - for example if the result is not a string I write to the console?

Comment: Just compose another observable and subscribe to it: `dialogRef.afterClosed().filter(result => typeof result !== 'string').do(result => console.log(result)).subscribe()`. Compose as many as you need. If the filter expresssions are mutually exclusive, only one will do something.