# Angular rxjs. combine multiple observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 observables:

1. `this.configsService.getConfigsList()`
2. `this.bcProductService.getProductById(config['id'])`

I can subscribe to both of them and use their data.

I want to get the configs list and map each config item with its corresponding product (using the config.id)... Something like this.

```
    const configs = this.configsService.getConfigsList;
    const product= (id)=> this.bcProductService.getProductById(id);
    configs.pipe(
        concatMap(val => product(val['id']).map(t=>val['p']=t) )
    ).subscribe(test => {
        console.log('configs with products: ', test);
    });
```

but that is not working. the above does not print an error or the console.log. I see several examples of this online but i just can seem to get it working. Thank you for helping.

### another attempt

this is the example from https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html but i get the following error.

> core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: combinedProject.subscribe is not a function

```
configsWithP(): any {
    const configs = this.configsService.getConfigsList;
    const product = this.bcProductService.getProductById(124);
    const combinedProject = combineLatest( configs, product, (c, p) => {
        return `c: ${c}, p: ${p}`;
    });
    // log values
    const subscribe = combinedProject.subscribe(latestValuesProject =>
        console.log(latestValuesProject)
    );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is combineLatest

Comment: the console log from above will look like this `configs with products:  Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}` but no data

Comment: i can see here how to get both calls combined but i need to add the data together in s specific structure. like above. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer after we discussed it in chat and made a solution. The `getConfigLists` returns an Observable that emits arrays of config objects. Then for every object in the array the corresponding product needs to be retrieved from a service and merged with the config object. After that it needs to again come out as an observable that emits the array of config object.

This is the solution:

```
private configsWithP(): any {
  const configs = this.configsService.getConfigsList;
  const combinedConfigs = configs.pipe(
    flatMap((configsArray) => {
      const getProductObservablesArray = configsArray.map((config) => this.bcProductService.getProductById(124));
      return zip(...getProductObservablesArray, (...args: any[]) => args).pipe(
        map(products => {
          for (let i = 0; i < configsArray.length; i++) {
            configsArray[i]['p'] = products[i];
          }
          return configsArray;
        })
      )
  }));
  combinedConfigs.subscribe(configss=> {
    console.log(configss);
  });
}
```

Here is also a sample on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hxeg2) that works. I did not create services I create observables and combine them. Check the console there and you will see the output.

Comment: yes you understand correctly. What you provided did not return an error and nothing was logged to the console

Comment: it may help to know that the `configs` return looks like `[ {}, {} ]`

Comment: Maybe the problem is the call to `getConfigsList` and should be `getConfigList()` instead. I updated the sample with a link to my working code.

Comment: I see so it is an array not an observable. I will then change the code.

Comment: yes ur example on stackBiz is what i need. But when mapping the configs return the config is showing all of the configs instead of the individual

Comment: I see then the configs is an observable that returns an array of all the configs at once. I will update the code to take this into consideration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184842/discussion-between-omar-and-alesd).